Deployment of Griddb database with Terraform
I want to create an IaC script using Terraform, it will create a set of resources in AWS. One of the resources is an Ubuntu virtual machine that will run a GridDB database. I used this doc as a starting point - https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/using-apt/. According to the document, the default admin credentials are admin/admin, I'd like my script to change the password to some unique value (which will be unique for each customer). I am not quite sure how to proceed, since the command "gs_passwd admin" expects me to write the new password interactively. The example of code is shown below, could you please advise?
resource "aws_instance" "db01" {
    ami = "ami-0750f57b80795fb10"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    user_data = <<-EOF
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.5 multiverse" >  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list
        wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | apt-key add -
        apt update
        apt install griddb-meta
        systemctl start gridstore
        gs_passwd admin
        EOF
    user_data_replace_on_change = true
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.group01.id]
    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }  
    tags = {
        name = "Database Node"
    }
}


This in particular does not look like a terraform problem, rather of the tool you're trying to use. I would advise reading through their docs on how to change the default username and password.

The docs already document you can give the password to the command with the -p flag https://griddb.net/en/docs/GridDB_OperationGuide.html#sec-5.5.3

First of all, it is not a good practice to use "user_data" property for multi-line scripts, I'd recommend to create a separate file and use the templatefile reference.
Second, you need to run gs_passwd as gsadm user, and use -p key to set the password.
Additionally, you can use some of the AWS account properties as a unique string used for password, sending it to the script as a variable. For example:

separate file script.sh


#!/bin/bash
    echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.5 multiverse" >  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list
    wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | apt-key add -
    apt update
    apt install griddb-meta
    systemctl start gridstore
    sudo -u gsadm gs_passwd admin -p ${passw}




Terraform script:




resource "aws_instance" "db01" {
    ami = "ami-0750f57b80795fb10"
    instance_type = "t2.micro" 
    #below Amazon VPC is used as a unique string
    user_data =  templatefile("script.sh", {
        passw = data.aws_vpc.default.id
    })
    user_data_replace_on_change = true
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.group01.id]
    lifecycle {
        create_before_destroy = true
    }  
    tags = {
        name = "Database Node"
    }  
}

data "aws_vpc" "default" {
    default = true
}

output "db_password" {
    value = data.aws_vpc.default.id
    description = "the temporary password of the default database admin user"
}



